# Web app performance monitoring on AWS

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch

I've been using AWS only for a while and wasn't even looking at other cloud platforms but recently I saw a demo of Application Insights in Azure where a guy showed how he was monitoring the performance of a web application. I need the same for my application in Amazon: to have tools which would allow me to understand which requests took longer to process, how long the user was waiting for response etc. For example how they do it in Azure: [image]

Not sure if it's possible in AWS, I couldn't find enough information. Would be great if someone pointed me in a right direction, I hope Amazon has similar functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: Google analytics has things very similar to this but I haven't seen anything on AWS that does this.  I'd be interested in understanding how Azure can track SSL requests.

Comment: SSL would not be a problem, the application is behind ELB, everything which goes after ELB is unencrypted.

Comment: You want [Application Performance Monitoring](https://www.gartner.com/reviews/market/apm).

Comment: @anothermh I don't see Amazon in the list. I was asking about AWS only.

Comment: @DimaShcherbakov The list I gave you is _the list_, and if there is no solution listed there that meets your needs then the solution does not exist in the market, which answers your question.

Comment: @anothermh Thank you, that answers my question! It's pretty upsetting though..

Comment: @DimaShcherbakov Just do what everyone else does and [use New Relic](https://newrelic.com/application-monitoring). They probably have [an agent for your platform](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/manage-apm-agents/installation/compatibility-requirements-new-relic-agents#apm-compatibility).

Answer (score 3):

I believe the [AWS X-Ray service](https://aws.amazon.com/xray/) may be able to provide this type of monitoring.

In the past I've used [New Relic](https://aws.amazon.com/featured-partners/newrelic/) for this sort of thing.

You could probably also pull this information from your ELB logs, and build reports using the [Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/) and [QuickSight](https://quicksight.aws/) services. That's a lot to set up though.

Comment: Will take a closer look on X-Ray, thanks. The application is able to report response times for requests but how can I use that data with CloudWatch? It's pretty easy to export numbers but not requests etc.

Comment: You shouldn't write off third-party services like New Relic either. Sometimes, like in this instance, they are way easier to use than the AWS equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Azure has Application Insights, Amazon has CloudWatch.

However, the graphs that Azure displays look nicer visually. The key question is: do the respective services offer data monitoring for the key features that you require?

CloudWatch can provide you with a massive amount of data if setup correctly.

Comment: Correct. That's why I'm asking, I couldn't find a way to configure CloudWatch for that.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Configure CloudWatch for what?
(collecting data or displaying data). There are a lot of good resources on CloudWatch on Amazon's web site, YouTube, etc. Also look into Amazon QuickSight. If you are looking for pretty graphics, I think a third party service is the best option.

Comment: Configure CloudWatch for taking data from some datasource (like ELB, application logs etc) and display required fields like on the screenshot. 
Third party is not a fun option, I refuse to believe that Azure can do that but not Amazon.

Comment: Almost all Amazon services have the ability to send data, metrics, logs, etc. to CloudWatch. This is configured at the service level (e.g. for load balancers, enable logging in the load balancer console). For some data, such as web server log files, you will need to configure an agent in the instance to send data to CloudWatch (Azure needs an agent too!). CloudWatch is a BIG service with lots and lots of options.